# Change default <> arrow head separate from >

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I can change the default arrow head via `\tikzset{>=Latex}`. However, it is not a given that the combination of an arrow head and its reverse looks good, so I would like to also change `<>` to something custom.

I have, on a hunch, tried `\tikzset{<>={Diamond[scale=1.2]}}` but that doesn't seem like the right syntax. Is there a way to set a default arrow head for `<>` endings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define the `<>` arrow tip via the `.tip` handler (cf. section 16.4.4 "Defining Shorthands", pgfmanual):

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
    >={Latex[]},
    <>/.tip={Diamond[scale=1.2]},
  }
  \draw[dashed,->] (0,0) -- (5,0);
  \draw[-<>] (0,2) -- (5,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should create a style with `tikzset`
[image: myarr]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{myarr/.style={{Diamond[scale=1.2]}-{Diamond[scale=1.2]}}}
        \draw[myarr] (0,0) -- (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Right, but I'd like to use the intuitive `<>` syntax, i.e. I'd still like to write `\draw[<>-<>] ...`.